# Converting string array to int array for sql statement

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, entity-framework-core

In my model I have:

```
public List<uint> Ids {get; set;}
```

I am executing SQL in my get call and the format for the Ids are not in proper format for the SQL statment to successfully execute.

```
db.tableName.FromSql("SELECT * FROM tableName where( id in ({0}) && itemId = {1})", x.Ids, x.ItemId);
```

Currently, my x.Ids looks like this:

> [0]: 100 [1]: 101

I want for my x.Ids to look like 100, 101 so that in my `where` clause they will look like `id in (100, 101)`.

I have tried: `var temp = string.Join(', ', x.Ids); //result: "100, 101"` but this is a string array and I want Int array for the SQL to work. 
The variable `x` is being passed to my method.

Is there a simple way to make this conversion or do I have to loop through the string array and convert and push into int array?

Comment: Probably because this allows a Sql Injection attack.  Also there really isn't enough information to answer the question.  What is `db`?  What is `tableName`?  I've not seen `FromSql()` and none of those look like standard .Net classes nor methods..

Comment: 1. x.ids looks like "[0]: 100 [1]: 101" - what exactly does "look like" mean? 2. an `int` array can't contain commas or "look like" anything, `Join` is correct - so what exactly do you mean? 3. I don't think you understand `FromSql` or SQL `IN` - suggest you look into it.

Comment: Take a look at Dapper. Your SQL injection issue will go away, and it's capable of handling

Comment: There is no possibility of a SQL injection if both of the parameters are integers, the OP has not commented on the datatype of `x.ItemId`, but that is ancillary to the question. A minimal example implies that obfuscation and omission be applied.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, "What is db? What is tableName? I've not seen FromSql()" The intention of the statement is clear, if not to implementation, but to context:  Run the query and return the results. This comes from Microsoft Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Given an array you can use the [`Array.ConvertAll` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx):

```
int[] myInts = Array.ConvertAll(x.Ids, int.Parse);
```

A LINQ solution is similar, except you would need the extra `ToArray` call to get an array:

```
int[] myInts = x.Ids.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: So, essentially, ``Array.ConvertAll()`` is a ``map`` function over arrays?

Comment: @dumetrulo, Yes, but is still has to iterate through all of the values converting each one individually. The LINQ version either the one given or `.ConvertAll(Converter<T>,<U> converter )`. For the latter to work, you must define the `converter()` method, but it permits custom type conversions like `map`.

Comment: Do you mean `Array.map()` from Javascript?

Comment: I was thinking more in terms of F# but sure, JavaScript's is very similar.